How to get urn for https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts
I want any users with linkedIn profile to have ability to share posts from my app to their LinkedIn pages. The problem is that I need URN of user as required field, but I can't receive it
I get auth code with https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&state=123456&scope=profile%20r_emailaddress%20w_member_social%20openid, in scope I put all posible options from OAuth 2.0 scopes,
after it I run https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&code=${authCode}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri} to get access_token, next step is https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo with header Authorization: Bearer access_token' and in response I get:
{
"serviceErrorCode": 100,
"message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET /userinfo",
"status": 403
}
How to solve this problem?

Does this answer your question? LinkedIn API How to get Userinfo?

after changing request for auth code to https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&state=123456&scope=openid%20profile%20w_member_social%20email
I seccesfuly receive response for https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo but in this response there no URN
The info in responce is:
{
"sub": "",
"email_verified": true,
"name": "",
"locale": {
"country": "US",
"language": "en"
},
"given_name": "",
"family_name": "",
"email": "",
"picture": ""
}
